# Open source Java EE portal platform which is OSGI compliant?

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, portal

I need to find an open source Java EE portal solution (portlet container, cms etc) which would be OSGI compliant. I've only found Apache Jetspeed which was supposed to have this ability in 2.2.2 version and it doesn't seem to be maintained.

Unfortunately none of the usual suspects does support OSGI. 
Is there anything well documented out there that would support it?

What I mean by OSGI support is:

1) ability to load modules using OSGI spec without the need to restart

2) (optionally) ability to install the whole portal in a OSGI container in an OSGI compliant application server

Liferay indeed does have SOME support for OSGI in current version, but I have to be sure that there's a way to deploy an OSGI bundles without a restart and how to do it.

Comment: I thought the latest Liferay does support OSGi or at least works on top of it ....

Comment: that's true.. or at least they said the latest version of Liferay will use OSGI for it's modularity...

Comment: Guys, please... since you don't even post a single link, it's obvious that it doesn't support OSGI. 6.2 version is scheduled for Q3 2013, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

A core Liferay architect [*recently stated*](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/why-osgi-and-liferay-) the reason why he eventually wants to make Liferay based on OSGi.

He specifically states:

> My current focus, as far as development is concerned, is almost 100% OSGi.
>   A usable form of OSGi integration will arrive in 6.2.

Since 6.2 is undergoing development and will be released later this year, you might want to check out its latest milestone (6.2.0 M4 at the time of this answer) from the [*SourceForge archives*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/) and see if you can base your project on it, upgrading to the stable release when it's ready.

Comment: " you might want to check out its latest milestone (6.2.0 M4 at the time of this answer) from the SourceForge archives and see if you can base your project on it"

I've asked the question and started the bounty precisely to get answer for this question.